# Is there a need to define client.setDefaultUri in Configuration class of Web-service client

Tags: web-services, spring-boot

My code for SOAP WS client Config.java looks like below:

```
@Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this is the package name specified in the <generatePackage> specified in
        // pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.example.howtodoinjava.schemas.school");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public SOAPConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SOAPConnector client = new SOAPConnector();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:8080/service/student-details");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
```

Do I need to mandatorily set DefaultUri as mentioned in the service class.